# ios Iphone X show home indicator only when dragging from bottom

Tags: ios, swift

I have number of viewControllers which are embedded by navigation controller.

All I want is to hide home indicator for iphone X on **all** View Controllers (**by default**) and only show the indicator when user is dragging up from bottom.

Tried this:

```
override func prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
```

But it hides the "Home Indicator" only after the View Controller did appear (with a delay).

Comment: Is it flashing on every screen, or only once when the app opens.

Comment: on every screen

Comment: I assume this is by design: it is a visual indicator to the user that they can still swipe (and where to swipe from) to get to the home screen.

Comment: How are you presenting each View Controller? `Tab` and `Nav` should be calling into their child view controllers for the property so it probably shouldn't be flashing.

Comment: Could you add some more details please?
Each View Controller is presentring by this:

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(aViewController, animated: true)

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple's documentation on [`prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/2887510-prefershomeindicatorautohidden) this might not be possible.

> **Discussion**
>   Override this method to signal your preference for displaying the
>   visual indicator. The system takes your preference into account, but
>   returning `true` is **no guarantee that the indicator will be hidden.**

(emphasis added)

You could also try calling [`setNeedsUpdateOfHomeIndicatorAutoHidden()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/2887509-setneedsupdateofhomeindicatoraut) in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`, but again, there's no guarantee it'll hide.

I'm not aware of any other methods to force this to disappear.